# How to factor out $x$ from $(x^n+1)^\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, factoring

How do we factor x out of $(x^n+1)^\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: $$\left(x^n+1\right)^{1/n}=x\left(1+x^{-n}\right)^{1/n}$$

Comment: I do not know the context of your question, but if you want to factor $x$ in the 1st power you would do:

\begin{align}
[x^{n} (1 + \frac{1}{x^{n}})]^\frac{1}{n} = (x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} (1 + \frac{1}{x^{n}})^{\frac{1}{n}} = x (1 + \frac{1}{x^{n}})^{\frac{1}{n}}
\end{align}

Comment: @algevristis thats exactly what i needed. thanks sm

Comment: @Neels I will add that as answer if you can approve it so that more people will get helped in the future.

Comment: @algevristis sure, i will approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} \left[x^{n} (1 + \frac{1}{x^{n}})\right]^\frac{1}{n} = (x^{n})^{\frac{1}{n}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x^{n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = x \left(1 + \frac{1}{x^{n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \end{align}

Comment: For $x=-1$ and $n=2$ the formula is wrong.